# Minimum Vertex Cover on a Single Vertex

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is the minimum vertex cover on a graph with just one vertex, with no edges, 0 or 1?

I think it is 0 because there are no edges and hence no vertices need to be in the minimum vertex cover to satisfy the property that every edge must have at least one endpoint in the vertex cover set.

I am just not sure if there is a rule that says |minimum vertex cover| is strictly positive.

Thanks :)

Comment: So is that to say 'a graph on one vertex (with no edges) simply doesn't have a vertex cover' ?

Comment: I was wrong, you are correct.  See the formal [definition here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

Comment: See I looked at that before but I'm not sure...do you think we could use the property that ' the number of vertices of a graph is equal to its minimum vertex cover number plus the size of a maximum independent set (Gallai 1959)' ? And the independent set would just be size 1, so therefore min vertex cover is 0?

Comment: The definition applies.  If there are *no edges* (regardless of one or more vertices), no vertices are needed in the "vertex cover" to satisfy the covering condition (which is vacuously true).

Comment: Great thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition applies.  If there are *no edges* (regardless of one or more vertices), no vertices are needed in the "vertex cover" to satisfy the covering condition (which is vacuously true).